# Xpath syntax when scraping headlines from CNN homepage

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I tried to scrape [CNN homepage](https://cnn.com) with `scrapy`. 
I used the following `xpath` selectors, but all of them returned empty lists.

**Current results :** all of these returns `[]`

```
"//strong"
"//h2"
"//span[@class='cd__headline-text']"
```

**Expected results :**

```
[Headline_1, Headline_2, Headline_3, ...]
```

Can someone help me figure out why?
Is CNN doing something to stop people from scraping headlines?

I use `Scrapy`.

Comment: Please edit your question to Include the site link, current result you are having and the desired result to get a quicker response.

Comment: Scrapy does not support JavaScript.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to write XPath/CSS selector or any web page, first of all, check page source that whether the selectors which you are looking for exists or not. In the current case none of the above selectors are found in page source. They are getting page content in various requests, try checking the network and find appropriate requests for your case. You need to make those requests in your spider in order to scrape news from CNN.